# Drawing elements for p5.js and babylon.js in same canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas, p5.js, babylonjs

I want to create 3D shape on my canvas, but I am using `ml5.js`and `posenet` example. There are two ways I could think of:

**Approach 1:** Using WEBGL renderer. But, it does not work. WEBGL renderer is required to make 3d shapes run, right? The following is *NOT* working when I use it with ml5.js example:

```
createCanvas(640,480, WEBGL)
```

**Approach 2**: Use a different library. I decided to use `babylon.js`

But it requires that I create a canvas element first and then do the diplay.

```
  <canvas id="renderCanvas" touch-action="none"></canvas> 
    var canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas"); // Get the canvas element 
    var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(defaultCanvas0, true); // Generate the BABYLON 3D engine
    //  Add the create scene function
```

**Problem:** The canvas created by p5 is different from that of the babylon.js. I want the display to be one and not two separate windows. How to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Can you specify the **exact** p5.js code which don't works in WEBGL mode ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot use two renderers on the same webgl context of a canvas.
Which means, you will need to select one of the renderers to draw your 3D shape.

The canvas creation can be a part of the code, so you don't really have to already have the canvas in your HTML. Babylon.js simply needs to canvas in the engine's constructor:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
// style your canvas
canvas.style.width = "100px";
canvas.style.height = "100px";
// add to wherever you want
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// use this canvas to init babylon
var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);
// do your thing!
```